# Tight box around siunitx degree

Tags: siunitx, bounding-box

I want the box around the degree symbol to be like the one around the exponent on the `x`. I thought `\mbox{}` would do it, but it does not seem to in this case.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\let\OldSIUnitSymbolDegree\SIUnitSymbolDegree
\renewcommand{\SIUnitSymbolDegree}{\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\mbox{\ensuremath{\OldSIUnitSymbolDegree}}}}

\begin{document}

\ang{60} \SI{60}{\degree}

$x^{\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{$\scriptstyle 2$}}$ % <-- want a tight box like this
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to put the box *inside* the superscript and allow for the kerns, something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\renewcommand\SIUnitSymbolDegree
  {\ensuremath{^{\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\ensuremath{\kern-\scriptspace\scriptstyle\circ\kern-2\scriptspace}}}}}

\begin{document}

\ang{60} \SI{60}{\degree}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Any reason why you didn't just use the `\OldSIUnitSymbolDegree`?

Comment: @PeterGrill Yes: if you trace that definition through it has the superscript inside it, coming out to `{}^{\circ}` if you've not altered it. That _won't work_ for what you want.